# If a cell value equals this, another cell equals that

Tags: excel, formula

I have a spreadsheet with a column for cities, of which their are only 4 different values. What is the formula for equating a new column to show the corresponding state and apply it to the entire list? Example:

Atlanta equals GA,
Phoenix equals AZ,
Chicago equals IL,
Nashville equals TN

Thanks!!

Comment: You'll need a lookup table for corresponding states to cities. Do you have a table?

Comment: I just created a table, and expanded it to include zip code.  I think i'm struggling with the VLOOKUP formula.  I'm basically trying to say, if the city is Atlanta then the state is GA and the zip is 30328.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: You can set up one table with 3 columns: city, state abbrev, and zip, and use `VLOOKUP` to fetch any of the information. You do need to spell the city correctly, or use the "closest match" option. If you've set this up but having trouble getting `VLOOKUP` working, you should post that code so we can help find out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the VLookup function for that:

Make a table with your city name in one column and the state in the next column.  Then the following formula next to the city that you want populated:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,A$20:B$23,2,FALSE)
```

In this example, the city you want to identify is in A1, and this formula goes in B1.  You can copy it down to B2, B3, etc because the table is hard-coded as A$20:B$23, rather than A20:B23 (where each successive copy down the column would look for a table one row down as well).  This example put the lookup table in the A-B columns, but you could put it anywhere you like.

The FALSE at the end means, look for an exact match, not closest.  So if you get a "Dallas" in your list, the function will return NA rather than guessing between the state for Chicago and the state for Nashville (either side of Dallas, alphabetically).

Hope that helps!

EDIT:
You added that you also need zipcode info, and that's easy enough to add.

Your table that defines everything would put the zipcode in the 3rd column, so down at A20:B23 (in my example above) you'd end up with A20:C23, where the table would look like

```
Atlanta   GA   12345
Chicago   IL   23456
Nashville TN   34567
Phoenix   AZ   45678
```

The cell next to your city in the table you want to populate would be in B1 as shown above giving the state, and then in C1 you'd have the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,A$20:C$23,3,FALSE)
```

The changes are that here the table is defined out to column C, and instead of "2" returning the second column (i.e. the state abbreviation shown in B), it returns the zipcode shown in column C, the third column.

Again, hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I think I'm getting close. Does the table just go in the spreadsheet itself?  I created at table where city is S2 and State abbrv. is T2.  My table ranges from S2-S12 and T2-T12 respectively. The column i'm trying to populate would the state abbreviation ranging from O2-O590

Comment: Glad to help.  Just to answer what you asked (you got it, but somebody else may wonder): yes, you can put the table you've made with each city, state, and zip anywhere in the worksheet; the VLookup() function just points to it. Above or off to the side of the data you're working with both work well. To keep the sheet visually clean, you may want to hide the rows or columns with the lookup table. This makes the sheet cleaner to look at, but if you need to modify the lookup table, it's not as obvious where to find it.  Designer's call if that's a worthwhile tradeoff or not.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention "only 4 different values" maybe:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(LEFT(A1),{"A","P","C","N"},0),"GA","AZ","IL","TN")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) Table that contains the city and state abbreviation.

Here is a table that has the Capital, State, State Abbreviation.

```
Montgomery  Alabama AL
Juneau  Alaska  AK
Phoenix Arizona AZ
Little Rock Arkansas    AR
Sacramento  California  CA
Denver  Colorado    CO
Hartford    Connecticut CT
Dover   Delaware    DE
Tallahassee Florida FL
Atlanta Georgia GA
Honolulu    Hawaii  HI
Boise   Idaho   ID
Springfield Illinois    IL
Indianapolis    Indiana IN
Des Moines  Iowa    IA
Topeka  Kansas  KS
Frankfort   Kentucky    KY
Baton Rouge Louisiana   LA
Augusta Maine   ME
Annapolis   Maryland    MD
Boston  Massachusetts   MA
Lansing Michigan    MI
Saint Paul  Minnesota   MN
Jackson Mississippi MS
Jefferson City  Missouri    MO
Helena  Montana MT
Lincoln Nebraska    NE
Carson City Nevada  NV
Concord New Hampshire   NH
Trenton New Jersey  NJ
Santa Fe    New Mexico  NM
Albany  New York    NY
Raleigh North Carolina  NC
Bismarck    North Dakota    ND
Columbus    Ohio    OH
Oklahoma City   Oklahoma    OK
Salem   Oregon  OR
Harrisburg  Pennsylvania    PA
Providence  Rhode Island    RI
Columbia    South Carolina  SC
Pierre  South Dakota    SD
Nashville   Tennessee   TN
Austin  Texas   TX
Salt Lake City  Utah    UT
Montpelier  Vermont VT
Richmond    Virginia    VA
Olympia Washington  WA
Charleston  West Virginia   WV
Madison Wisconsin   WI
Cheyenne    Wyoming WY
```

Then you would use `=VLOOKUP(A1,A1:C50,3, FALSE)` to look for A1 (Montgomery) in the table and it would output `AL` for example.